# How to append a unique number to an index that resets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating an indexing id type system.

The way I am wanting it to work is the following:

A11 is showing "180 DAYS". A `VLOOKUP` is setup to search the key at Q3:R9. This generates an letter that is associated to the "Bucket". Below is what I have to create that. As you can see if works.

```
=(VLOOKUP($A11,Q3:R9,2,FALSE))
```

What I am having trouble figuring out what to do is how to append a number after the letter that increases by 1 that resets with a new letter. For instance, I know that I could check the cell above and simple do a +1, but that won't help reset the number when a new number (bucket selection) comes up.

This is how I am wanting it to work.

A1

A2

A3

A4

B1

B2

Etc.

How can I change my formula to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in`B11` and populate down:

```
=VLOOKUP($A11,Q$3:R$9,2,FALSE) & COUNTIF(A$11:A11,A11)
```

Sample:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!